# How to configure log4j to log Spring injections

Tags: spring, log4j

How can I configure log4j to write an entry to the log every time it injects a class?

My use case is this: I have Autowiring enabled. I have some interfaces with multiple implementing classes. I want to be able to see in the log which impl class gets injected to another class.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you using autowiring on your setter methods or on the fields themselves? If you have setter methods defined then perhaps you could use Spring's AOP support to define a pointcut on the setters you're interested in and write an advice to log the details of what's being injected.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I configure log4j to write an entry to the log every time it injects a class?  ... Any thoughts?

My thought is that the *real* problem is to get Spring or your application to *generate* the log events; e.g. to call the relevant methods on a `Logger` at the relevant point.